# Email id in URL?

Tags: url, web-applications

Is there any issues with having one's email id in the URL for a web application?

a) Technically, is this an issue?

b) Or is it some kind of convention to NOT have the email id in the URL? And rather have something like /user/:id?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by E-Mail ID, the E-Mail address?

Comment: I have had many clients (mostly from India) who call an E-Mail Address an E-Mail ID.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Message-ID: Also an automatically generated field; used to prevent multiple delivery and for reference in In-Reply-To"

Comment: but he didn't call it a "Message-ID:" - it's semantics I know.  I was simply pointing out that it's standard practice is some parts of the world to call it an Email-ID.  Now I will mention that it drove me insane when they called it email id too...

Comment: Sorry about that confusion! Yes, I mean email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's being passed via clear text, it can be intercepted and harvested by spammers.  It is good practice to encrypt it before passing, and decrypt it on the other end.

Comment: I agree with rockinthesixstring. message-ID's in clear-text URL could allow for someone to do email-spoofing

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question. So, essentially, it's not really a technical issue; more of a convention.

Since the entire connection is over https, I don't think that address spoofing will be possible.